# Deep lowercase inside files inside folders inside a path

Tags: python, linux, file, directory, lowercase

Ok, this is the thing, I have been working on a project under Windows (not mine) and finally they decided to have a fully functional fork on Linux, the main problem is that the original programmers coded regarless the cases, opening and calling things using upercase o lowercase at will...crazy...right? Well, I managed to produce a python3 script to flat all the cases to lower in folders and files, but still I had to fix all that changes inside the files, it means to keep all the changes done "in memory" and check all the files inside the project and update each of them. Well, it worked 95%  more or less, still got a LOT of uncorrected files...my head can't find the "why" at this moment, any suggestions?

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os
import re
import time
import string
import mimetypes
import subprocess

keys = set()

def flat(path):
    list = os.listdir(path)
    for item in list:
        obj = os.path.normpath(path+item)
        obj_new = os.path.normpath(path+item.lower())
        if os.path.isfile(obj):
            keys.add(item)
            if item!=item.lower():
                print('[Yes]',obj, '-->', obj_new)
                os.replace(obj, obj_new)
            else:
                print('    [No]',obj)
        else:
            obj = obj + '/'
            flat(obj)
            item = item + '/'
            keys.add(item)
            if item!=item.lower():
                print('[Yes]',obj, '-->', obj_new)
                os.replace(obj, obj_new)
            else:
                print('    [No]',obj)

def insidefix(path, keys):
    list = os.listdir(path)
    for item in list:
        obj = os.path.normpath(path+item)
        if os.path.isfile(obj):        
            (mime,enc) = mimetypes.guess_type(obj)
            parts = re.split('\.', item)
            ext = parts[len(parts)-1]
            if mime!=None:
                t = re.split('/', mime)
                if (t[0]=='text') | (ext in set):
                    print('Fixing -->',obj, '|', mime)
                    for ref in keys:
                        pattern = ''
                        for c in range(len(ref)):
                            if (ref[c].isalpha()):
                                pattern=pattern+'['+ref[c].upper()+ref[c].lower()+']'
                            else:
                                 pattern = pattern + ref[c]
                        arg= 's|'+pattern+'|'+ref.lower()+'|g'
                        subprocess.call(["/bin/sed", "-i", arg, obj])
                        print("/bin/sed", "-i", arg, obj)
        else:
            obj = obj + '/'
            insidefix(obj, keys)

def runingtime(t):
    h=m=s=0
    for i in range(t):
        if s==60:
            m+=1
            s=0
        if m==60:
            h+=1
            m=0
        s+=1
    print(h,':',m,':',s)

path = '/warehouse/projects/igp/'
set=['php','txt','css','log','sym','map','htm','thmx','xml','mht','ini','js','html','backup','qry','config','json']
begin = time.time()
flat(path)
print('***********************************')
for k in keys:
    print(k)
print('***********************************')
insidefix(path, keys)
end = time.time()
dif = end-begin
final = int(dif)
runingtime(final)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please decompose your problem.

You can either go top-down or bottom-up. I recommend bottom-up.

That is, descend to leaf directory, list **all files** (1) there, rename these files. Step out, rename that leaf directory. Step out, ...

Code:

```
def descend(path):
    for item in list(os.scandir(path)):
        if item.is_dir():
            descend(item.path)
        if item.name != item.name.lower():
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, item.name), os.path.join(path, item.name.lower()))
```

Initial state:

```
air:~ dima$ find testdir
testdir
testdir/lo.txt
testdir/lower
testdir/lower/lo1.txt
testdir/lower/UP1.txt
testdir/UP.txt
testdir/UPper
```

Final state:

```
air:~ dima$ find testdir
testdir
testdir/lo.txt
testdir/lower
testdir/lower/lo1.txt
testdir/lower/up1.txt
testdir/up.txt
testdir/upper
```

(1) you should list all files in advance, i.e. `list(os.scandir(...))` because you don't want to modify the directory while you are reading it. While that's technically safe on modern operating systems, it can lead to mysterious logical bugs. Hint: order of items in a directory may change when you rename an item.

Comment: Brilliant solution!...it shows me that I'm just new in Python...But I still need to update the references inside the code lines (to the new folder names and file names), can't be done by hand, there is too much code and too many references to be fixed.

Comment: I'd try to use an IDE for bits inside code. You can record all renames made `FOO.H -> foo.h; SomeDir -> somedir` an then use e.g. `sed` on all your files, but it can also backfire, what if it's C++ and had `include <FOO>` (without `.h`) or if you start replacing all `s/FOO/foo/` it's easy to accidentally replace first word in `#define FOO_MAX 123`